# Load all table view cell images all together in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I want to load all table view cell images all together instead of waiting for scroll down. The images are loading from server. I can load all the images as data and store them in an array and show them. But is there any other way for this? Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you have to downloa all the images in your table view and just add this line of code [this reloadData];

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the images asynchronously in the `viewDidLoad` method, that way the user does not have to wait and can immediately start interacting with the UI. As long as the images haven't loaded (i.e. images array size is 0) you could show a generic image. Once you are done fetching you  can update the tableview by calling the [`reloadData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) method:

> For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible

As the user starts scrolling in the tableview, any subsequent loaded cells will now be able to access the populated images array in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.